# Warning in npm config at latest version

Tags: npm

I'm currently on npm@8.7.0 and every time I run any npm command I have this warning

```
npm WARN config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.
npm WARN config init.license Use `--init-license` instead.
```

Does anyone knows how to remove these warnings, my global .npmrc only set those above settings

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Alternatively, edit your `.npmrc` file and change "init.author.name" to "init-author-name".

For me, the full list of keys I had to change (replace . with -) was:

```
Old key                  New key
=======                  =======
init.author.name         init-author-name
init.author.email        init-author-email
init.author.url          init-author-url
init.license             init-license
```

The error/suggested fix returned was not helpful:

```
npm WARN config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.url Use `--init-author-url` instead.
npm WARN config init.license Use `--init-license` instead.
```

Had the warning been formatted slightly differently, perhaps a post here could have been avoided:

```
npm WARN config init.author.email Use `init-author-email` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `init-author-name` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.url Use `init-author-url` instead.
npm WARN config init.license Use `init-license` instead.
```

Comment: But what do you do if you need to switch back and forth between older and newer versions of npm?   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75189949/using-nvm-to-switch-between-npm-versions-and-dealing-with-init-author-name-needs

Comment: for who don't knows the `.npmrc` file will be in somthing like `C:\Users\YourUserName\.npmrc`

Comment: or better yet: "npm WARN config init.author.email deprecated. Use init-author-email instead."

Answer (score 11):

I set each one with the config setting the warning instructed.

i.e.

- npm config set init-license MIT
- npm config set init-version 0.0.1

Then delete the lines that contained the values in the old way:

- init.license = MIT
- init.version = 0.0.1

As a matter of testing, deleting the lines was enough to make the warning cease. However, after testing the values set in the new format; npm init was picking them up.

Answer (score 6):

***Some initial information***

> SO: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
> npm v: 8.11.0

---

npm `WARN` config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.
npm `WARN` config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.

---

**This worked for me .**

key=init.author.name || init-author-name
value=yourname

- `npm c set key=value`

Once the values ​​are entered, you need to remove the old keys.

- `npm c delete init.author.name`

**Did it solve your question?**
If you are interested in taking a look you can find more help by typing in your command line
***npm c -h***

[display example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuqDc.gif)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error I could not figure it out because my `~/.npmrc` was correct. And it turns out that I had `.npmrc` file in the root of my project with the exact same content (I have no idea why). Deleting that file solved the issue.