# Using nvm to switch between npm versions and dealing with init.author.name needs to be init-author-name

Tags: npm, nvm

I was on npm version 6 and when I moved to npm version 8.19.3, I got the warnings below whenever I issued any command:

```
npm --version
npm WARN config init.author.name Use `--init-author-name` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.email Use `--init-author-email` instead.
npm WARN config init.author.url Use `--init-author-url` instead.
npm WARN config init.license Use `--init-license` instead.
npm WARN config init.version Use `--init-version` instead.
8.19.3
```

I searched and found another user asked how to fix this warning, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71914123/warning-in-npm-config-at-latest-version), so I updated my `$HOME/.npmrc` file to use the new format (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72113809/3281336)) and it worked.

**However, because I use `nvm` to switch between different versions of npm**, I would like to have a solution that works for both the old and new versions of npm.

I tried to include syntax's for both the old and new config names as shown next:

```
# For npm 8.? and higher
init-author-name=Example name
init-author-email=name@example.com
init-author-url=https://www.example.com
init-license=MIT
init-version=1.0.0

# For npm < 8.?
init.author.name=Example name
init.author.email=name@example.com
init.author.url=https://www.example.com
init.license=MIT
init.version=1.0.0
```

But the above didn't work.  I was forced to delete the older syntax names to get rid of the warning messages.

So my question is:

**(Q) Is there a syntax that I can use that works for both the older versions of npm and the newer versions of npm?** Basically, I'd like not to have to manually edit my .npmrc file when I switch between older and newer versions when I use commands like:

```
nvm use 12.13.1
# Now I need the old config names (like init.author.name)

nvm use 8.19.3
# Now I need the new config names (like init-author-name)
```

As I said, I tried including both the old config names and the new names, but it didn't work.  **I was forced to remove the old names to get rid of the warnings.**  IMO, this is a bug.

Is there a solution to this problem?

#### Searching for a solution

I sited the question that I found on this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72113809/3281336